# why does the string get printed out as an argument? in c

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory, memory-management

why does the string `"test"` get printed out as an argument?

i am not passing a pointer to the string since i haven't allocated it before the argument

does the string argument "test" get stored somewhere i the memory heap?

```c
void printAstring(char * string){
    printf("%s",string);
}

 printAstring("test"); //Prints out test
```

usually if i want to pass a string as an argument to a `pointer as char parameter` i allocate the array of char and then pass it

```c
void printAstring(char * string){
    printf("%s",string);
}

char printThis[5]="test";

 printAstring(printThis); //Prints out test
```

Comment: **i allocate the array of char and then pass it** You don't do that for the `"%s"` argument to `printf()`. Why do you think this is any different?

Comment: Unrelated: `void printAstring(char * string)` should preferably be `void printAstring(const char *string)` since you are not allowed to make changes to the string literal `"test"` in the top version

Comment: the answer to your question is that a string literal is converted to pointer when it's passed as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost without exception when you write anything between double quotes, like this:

```
"string literal"
```

you are creating (you are asking the compiler to create) a read-only, anonymous array of `char`, of just the right size, initialized to contain that string.  And then since you're using this anonymous array in an expression where you need its value (in this case, so you can pass it to the `printAsString` function), the compiler automatically generates a pointer to the array's first element, just as it does for any array when you try to use its value.

In other words, when you wrote

```
printAstring("test");
```

what you got was more or less exactly as if you had written

```
const char __anonymous_array[] = "test";
printAstring(&__anonymous_array[0]);
```

The string (the anonymous array) is not stored on the heap, though; it's typically stored either with the program's initialized data, or perhaps (since it's readonly) with its code.

Comment: aah.. ok , well your answer says it all .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

A string constant is actually a `char` array stored in a read-only portion of memory.  So when you pass it to `printAsString` you're passing the address of the first element of the array where the string constant is stored.